# Query external table in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure Function (C#) to ingest data from an On-Premise SQL Server data table. I used the experimental External Table connector (*apiHubTable* for the technical name).

The connector retrieves data from my On-Premise table, but the query is not executed (I always have the full content of the table) :

```
Query query = Query.Parse($"LastUpdate &gt;\"{jobDefinition.LastExecutionDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")}\"");
var result = await eventsSqlTable.ListEntitiesAsync(query);
```

Here is the entity definition :

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

What language is used to express queries ? OData ? Another one ? Do you have any sample ?
Is this functionnality yet implemented ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is expressed in OData "language" ([OData website](http://www.odata.org/)), as the connection to the On Premise SQL Server is made throw the same data gateway than Logic App (Filter are expressed with OData in Logic App for the SQL Connector).

Here is a query sample :

```
$top=1000&$orderby=LastUpdate&$filter=year(LastUpdate) gt 2016 or (year(LastUpdate) eq 2016 and month(LastUpdate) gt 11 or (month(LastUpdate) eq 11 and day(LastUpdate) gt 3 or (day(LastUpdate) eq 3 and hour(LastUpdate) gt 11 or (hour(LastUpdate) eq 11 and minute(LastUpdate) gt 15 or (minute(LastUpdate) eq 15 and second(LastUpdate) ge 2)))))
```

**Note :** the date comparison is pretty complex because OData / the Data Gateway transforms datetime in datetimeoffset (T-SQL type). Some issues may occur if your table field is of type datetime.

This [pragamtica website](http://pragmatiqa.com/xodata/) hosts a tool that may help you to build your request, with a graphical tool.

Finally, here is the code used to build the last part of the filter:

```
public static string BuildDateFilter(string fieldName, DateTime dateToCompare)
{
    StringBuilder filterbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    filterbuilder.Append($"year({fieldName}) gt {dateToCompare.Year} or ("); // Or Year
    filterbuilder.Append($"year({fieldName}) eq {dateToCompare.Year} and ("); //And Year
    filterbuilder.Append($"month({fieldName}) gt {dateToCompare.Month} or ("); //Or Month
    filterbuilder.Append($"month({fieldName}) eq {dateToCompare.Month} and ("); //And Month
    filterbuilder.Append($"day({fieldName}) gt {dateToCompare.Day} or ("); //Or Day
    filterbuilder.Append($"day({fieldName}) eq {dateToCompare.Day} and ("); //And Day
    filterbuilder.Append($"hour({fieldName}) gt {dateToCompare.Hour} or ("); //Or Hour
    filterbuilder.Append($"hour({fieldName}) eq {dateToCompare.Hour} and ("); //And Hour
    filterbuilder.Append($"minute({fieldName}) gt {dateToCompare.Minute} or ("); //Or Minute
    filterbuilder.Append($"minute({fieldName}) eq {dateToCompare.Minute} and ("); //And Minute
    filterbuilder.Append($"second({fieldName}) ge {dateToCompare.Second}");
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //And Minute
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //Or Minute
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //And Hour
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //Or Hour
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //And Day
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //Or Day
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //And Month
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //Or Month
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //And Year
    filterbuilder.Append(")"); //Or Year    
    return filterbuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: May I ask you how did you include the query in the ListEntitiesAsync method? 

This works:

    `Query query = Query.Parse("$top=50");
    var list = await inputTable.ListEntitiesAsync(query);`

This doesn't:

    `Query query = Query.Parse("$filter=Id eq 5");
    var list = await inputTable.ListEntitiesAsync(query);`

Perhaps filtering is not implemented?